# Auto-generating Incorrect IntentService Default Constructor

Tags: android, shortcut

Android Studio has a useful shortcut to autogenerate required constructors and override methods (alt+enter).

For an IntentService, Android Studio auto-generates below default constructor which shows an error in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

//  Auto-generated by IDE
    public MyIntentService(String name) { super(name); }

//  This is the correct default constructor!
//  public MyIntentService() { super("MyIntentService"); }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@androidx.annotation.Nullable Intent intent) {
        ...
    }

}
```

The error in the AndroidManifest.xml is

> '...MyIntentService' has no default constructor

I understand how to manually correct this, but why is the IDE creating a wrong constructor? Is this a bug? Is there a way to correct this within the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's conincidental. I don't consider it to be a bug.

`IntentService` is an abstract class with one constructor, `IntentService(String)`. The intended usage is that the implementing subclass constructor calls it supplying a name that is useful for debugging.

On the other hand, Android `Service`s must have a no-arg constructor so the framework can instantiate them. It also applies to `IntentService`s.

The IDE know nothing about `IntentService` in particular. It just sees a constructor with a `String` argument and offers to generate a compatible subclass constructor. Another tool Android Lint later detects that there is a `Service` declared in manifest that does not have a no-arg constructor and emits a warning.

Note that with current background execution restrictions, you're likely better off using other mechanisms such as `JobIntentService` rather than `IntentService`.